# Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

what is this error ?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR in D:\xampp\htdocs\mehdi\application\libraries\phpass-0.1\PasswordHash.php on line 32
```

code:

```
$iteration_count_log2 = $params['phpass_hash_strength'];
        $portable_hashes = $params['phpass_hash_portable']; 
    var $itoa64; //line 32
    var $iteration_count_log2;
    var $portable_hashes;
    var $random_state;
```

Comment: Why, it's a syntax error, of course.

Answer (score 4):

You must not use **`var`** to declare a variable : just assign a value to it, when you need it :

```
$your_variable = 5647;
```

And if you really want your variables listed beforehand, just assign something that would mean *no-value* to them, like, for instance, null :

```
$your_variable = null;
```

Just so you know : `var` was used, in PHP 4 *(and, as such, is still valid in PHP 5, for that same usage)* to declare [classes properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: Help me understand **PHP**: Why is `var` used in some examples that I see? Is it for global variables?

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'var' from each of your variables.